# Azure deployment error > The size of the function content was too large

Tags: next.js, azure-deployment

Trying to deploy nexjs app to Azure via github but keep getting error message as below. I have tried everything mentioned in the previous conversation but no success. Please help me to fix it.

The content server has rejected the request with: BadRequest
Reason: The size of the function content was too large. The limit for this Static Web App is 104857600 bytes.

[image]

I tried different ways to deploy the app but still not working. Please help

Comment: Check the function which you are calling within the `api` folder.[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3tme.png)

Comment: Check the related github issue : https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/1034
There is a workaround here that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-nextjs-static-export?tabs=github-actions) to deploy Next JS app to Azure Static Web App.

***Steps for Static Generated NextJS***

- Create a `Azure Static Web App` in `Azure Portal`

[image]

- Select the code  which you have created in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/HarshithaVeeramalla/NextAppJan13).

[image]

- If your application does not contain any `API`, make sure you are leaving the `Api location` empty.

Provide the value only if you have any `API`.

As I don't have any API, so leaving the value as empty.

Check the build status in `GitHub Repository Actions`.

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

Also check the similar issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/214)

- Even I tried with [`Hybrid Next JS Application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-nextjs-hybrid).

***Build details for Hybrid Next JS***

[image]

Both worked for me without any issues.

[image]

***Output for API***

[image]

Comment: I followed that exact procedure, step by step, and got the exact same error.
I even tried to comment api_location in the workflow without success.