# unable to deploy next.js SSR in azure

Tags: next.js, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I successfuly deployed site using Azure static-Web-App using "next export" which create "out" folder for static pages. But i am using STRIPE payment intent in my next.js API folder. and i am unable to access api folder as site is deployed as static. while Azure claim that they handled [Deploy static-rendered Next.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-nextjs-static-export?source=recommendations&tabs=github-actions) in static web app. i also followed [Deploy hybrid Next.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-nextjs-hybrid)  but dont have any luck. This this https://stackoverflow.com/a/75107663 also discuss the same but i am unable to deploy the site as SSR.

Pakage.json:

```
  "scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start",
"lint": "next lint" },
```

Azure.yml file:

```
      app_location: "/" # App source code path
      api_location: "api" # Api source code path - optional
      output_location: "" # Built app content directory - optional
```

ERROR:
[image]

I also use

`next build && rm -rf ./.next/cache` 
for build to reduce size, but doesnt workout for me.

if i change pakage.json build command to "next build && next export"
it worked as static site but API not accessable. what to change in this so i can access backend API folder to achieve payment

Comment: Please share your GitHub Repo.

Comment: Unable to Open the given link.Please check once.

Comment: Will work on it and let you know.

Comment: i also tried changing api_location: "api" path to ".next/server/pages/api"? but still no success

Comment: @Harshitha any option that i can deploy and access webdomain/api/hello ? or have u tried?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252646/discussion-between-harshitha-and-saud00).