# Azure Static Web Apps - Limit 104857600 bytes

Tags: azure, github-actions, azure-static-web-app

I am trying to deploy a Retype app to Azure Static Web Apps using GitHub Actions. [Retype](https://retype.com/) is a tool that generates websites from Markdown files. However, I get the following error during the deployment:

> The size of the function content was too large. The limit for this Static Web App is 104857600 bytes.

I checked the size of my `wwwroot` folder, which contains the output of the Retype build, and it is about 50 MB (according to Windows Explorer). Also, the whole repo (in WinEx) is 90 MB.

I also checked the [quotas for Azure Static Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/quotas.), and it says that **the maximum size per app is 250 MB** for the Standard plan, which I am using.

So, I have two questions:

1. Am I correct in assuming that I should be able to create a Static Web App with a size of 250 MB like the documentation quota describes? Or, is there something that I am missing or misunderstanding that causes the quota to be lower and I can really only use 100 MB as my error describes?
2. If I should be able to use 250 MB, how can I achieve this?

I have tried some of the solutions suggested in these links, such as removing the cache folder or using a bundler, but they did not work for me. Also, I'm unsure how to apply 'solutions' that are for Next.js, since my page (Retype built) doesn't use this. [1](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/1034) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75076533/azure-deployment-error-the-size-of-the-function-content-was-too-large) [3](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/discussions/921#discussioncomment-4118632)

EDIT 1: `.github/workflows` code.

I have two `.yml` files in the workflows folder. Below are the two files and some of their code.

**retype-action.yml**

```yaml
build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed') || github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: publish
    name: Build and Deploy to Azure Static Web Apps
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.[AZURE SECRET] }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e., PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "/wwwroot/" # App source code path
          api_location: "/" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "" # Built app content directory - optional
          app_build_command: 'npm run build-ui-prod'
          api_build_command: 'npm run build-api-prod'
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.[AZURE SECRET] }}
          action: "close"
```

**azure...[secret].yml**

```yaml
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - published

  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - published

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed') || github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: true
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.[AZURE SECRET] }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e., PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "/wwwroot/" # App source code path
          api_location: "/" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "" # Built app content directory - optional
          app_build_command: 'npm run build-ui-prod'
          api_build_command: 'npm run build-api-prod'
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.[AZURE SECRET] }}
          action: "close"
```

In link 1 above, the app and api build commands were suggested as a solution, but this didn't work. The suggestion was:

```yaml
app_build_command: 'npm run build'
api_build_command: 'rm -rf ./node_modules/@next/swc-* && rm -rf ./.next/cache'
```

Comment: Please share your GitHub repo.

Comment: Che ck the Function in your App.

Comment: @Harshitha, I cannot share the repo - it is private. I have added `.github/workflows` files as an edit (based on the 'function' comment). If something else would be helpful, let me know. I'm not sure what to look for in the function.

Comment: How you have created your app?Try to reduce the size of the folder and check once.

Comment: does you app have a large number of dependencies? are they all configured correctly?

Comment: @Harshitha: I'm not sure how to respond to the question (how it was created). It has been created with the minimum setup necessary. There are no dependencies (@woodykiddy) that I am aware of. At the moment, the app is on the border of full - if I add something, it breaks, if I delete a file/folder, I get more space.